# How to find the class or procedure coding by myself in the Exception's stackTrace

Tags: java, exception

I am coding an Error Log Function.
So I need to log some information like operator,operate_time,error_message and api_name which CLASS or PROCEDURE the Exception be threw.
My problem is that I don't know how to get the api_name in java.
A part stacktrace of exception is(I hide name of my company):

```
com.xxxx.commons.database.DbException: {dbFlag: 101, dbMessage: ORA-01461}
    at com.xxxx.commons.database.DbHelper.throwDbException(DbHelper.java:933)
    at com.xxxx.commons.database.DbHelper.throwDbException(DbHelper.java:911)
    at com.xxxx.commons.database.DbHelper.runProcScalar(DbHelper.java:363)
    at com.xxxx.commons.database.DbHelper.runProcScalar(DbHelper.java:266)
    at com.xxxx.commons.database.DbHelper.runProcScalar(DbHelper.java:253)
    at com.xxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.saveErrorLog(xxxxxxxx.java:96)
    at com.xxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.save(xxxxxxxx.java:457)//I need this line
    at com.xxxx.xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.finishActivity(xxxxxx.java:410)
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.command.FinishActivityCommand.execute(xxxxxxxx.java:70)
    at com.xxxx.xxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.forward(xxxxxxx.java:79)
    at com.xxxx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.execute(FlowCtrlAction.java:50)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at com.xxxx.xxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.process(xxxxxxx.java:33)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
```

I need the className of the eighth line and my log function is the seventh line.
The java code is :

```
try{
    boolean r = store.xxxxxxx(caseId, runnerId, flowRecord);
    if (r) {
        return .........
    }
}catch(DbException e){
    saveLogDao.saveErrorLog(showType, businessUserId, caseId, stepCode, getExceptionStack(e), e.getMessage(), runnerId);
}
```

The function 'getExceptionStack(e)' is getting name of the exception class.
How to code it?Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure than **throws** the exception is the first one in stack. However, if I get your question right, you want to skip irrelevant methods and log some meaningful method into error log.

However, this might not be that trivial. If you have a method "getUserCredentials()", which calls "getUserName()", which calls "getDatabaseConnection()", which calls "connect()", which throws an exception - which method should be logged, when you call "getUserCredentials()"? Which method should be logged, when you call "getUserCredentials()" in "generateReport()", which was called in "main()" ?

However, there are some options, for example, analyzing annotations, especially if your code already uses some.

Here's an example where I annotate methods that should come up in a log when an exception happens deeper inside of them:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StackTrace {

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public static @interface TopLevelCallElement {

    }


    private void connect(){
        throw new RuntimeException("some database error");
    }

    private void getDatabaseConnection(){
        connect();
    }

    @TopLevelCallElement
    private void getName(){
        getDatabaseConnection();
    }

    @TopLevelCallElement
    public void getCredentials(){
        getName();
    }


    public static StackTraceElement getTopLevelFunction(Throwable exception){

        // iterate stack trace in reverse order
        StackTraceElement [] stackTrace = exception.getStackTrace();
        for (int i=stackTrace.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            StackTraceElement traceElement=stackTrace[i];
            try {
                Class<?> callerClass = Class.forName(traceElement.getClassName());

                for (Method method:callerClass.getDeclaredMethods()){
                    if (method.getName().equals(traceElement.getMethodName())){
                        // we got a method in a class that might be (unless it's an overloaded method)
                        // a method that really threw exception.
                        if (method.getAnnotation(TopLevelCallElement.class)!=null){
                            return traceElement;
                        }

                    }
                }

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // should not happen, we know we're callling Class.forName with existing classes

            }

        }

        // in case no apropriate stack trace element was found, just return the most deepest one
        return stackTrace[stackTrace.length-1];
    }

    public static void logExceptionElement(Throwable exception){
        StackTraceElement element = getTopLevelFunction(exception);
        System.err.println(String.format("Exception in class %s, method %s, line %d",
                element.getClass().getName(),
                element.getMethodName(),
                element.getLineNumber(),
                exception.getMessage()
                ));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackTrace test = new StackTrace();


        try{
            test.getCredentials();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException err){
            // should log "getCredentials()" as top level function exception point
            logExceptionElement(err);
        }


        try{
            test.getName();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException err){
            // should log "getName()" as top level function exception point
            logExceptionElement(err);
        }

    }

}
```

Annotating whole code like that just for logging purposes might be painful, however. You can, however, reuse some existing annotations, for example, Spring-based database application could track first "transactional" method in a stack. Other methods of analysis could involve skipping getters (any methods that begin with "get"), skipping certain classes by name/package name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to access the information in a stacktrace, you can use [Throwable#getStackTrace()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29), and then look for the line after the saveErrorLog.

getStackTrace() returns an array of [StackTraceElement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html), which contains the information you want.

I don't know how you're calling these methods, but a better option would be to pass in the name of the api from wherever you're calling this from.

Comment: Yeah,But the return value is an Array.I want the className (and the name of procdure be invoked) which throws this exception.Thank you :-)